# I need data in the order of month in year from March april may and then june

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT     MonthName, SUM(ExpenseClaimCount) AS Expr1, 'EXPENSE-CLAIM' AS ROW_TYPE
FROM         (SELECT     b.OrganisationID, a.ExpenseClaimCount, c.MonthName
                       FROM          Fact.MonthlyFactOrgMap AS a INNER JOIN
                                              Dim.DimOrganisation AS b ON a.DimOrganisationKey = b.DimOrganisationKey INNER JOIN
                                              Dim.DimDate AS c ON a.DateKey = c.DateKey
                       WHERE      (c.CalendarYear = 2014) AND (c.FullDate BETWEEN b.RowStartDate AND b.RowEndDate) AND (c.MonthName IN ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June')) AND 
                                              (a.ExpenseClaimCount > 0)) AS q
GROUP BY MonthName
UNION
SELECT     MonthName, SUM(FixedAssetCount) AS Expr1, 'FIXED ASSET' AS ROW_TYPE
FROM         (SELECT     b.OrganisationID, a.FixedAssetCount, c.MonthName
                       FROM          Fact.MonthlyFactOrgMap AS a INNER JOIN
                                              Dim.DimOrganisation AS b ON a.DimOrganisationKey = b.DimOrganisationKey INNER JOIN
                                              Dim.DimDate AS c ON a.DateKey = c.DateKey
                       WHERE      (c.CalendarYear = 2014) AND (c.FullDate BETWEEN b.RowStartDate AND b.RowEndDate) AND (c.MonthName IN ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June')) AND 
                                              (a.FixedAssetCount > 0)) AS q_2

GROUP BY MonthName
```

This is the query that I have ...all the suggestions below worked but not with union

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Have you considered using `ORDER BY c.Month`?

Comment: Without ordering by anything, it could be _any_ order.

Comment: `Answer needed soon` really funny!

Comment: lol @ Answer needed soon. Good luck with that attitude

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I very seldom use MySQL so I don't know all its quirks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `ORDER BY`

```
ORDER BY CHARINDEX(LEFT(MonthName,3),'AprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDecJanFebMar')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need data in a particular order, you should add a `group by` clause.  In this case, `group by monthname` will produce the alphabetical order you do not want.  So try this instead:

```
order by (case when MonthName = 'March' then 3
               when MonthName = 'April' then 4
               when MonthName = 'May' then 5
               when MonthName = 'June' then 6
          end)
```

Depending on the database there are simpler ways of expressing this idea.

EDIT:

Perhaps a better approach is to keep the minimum date for each month and use that for ordering.  Also, you don't need the subquery:

```
  SELECT c.MonthName, SUM(a.ExpenseClaimCount) as expr1, 'EXPENSE-CLAIM' AS ROW_TYPE
   FROM Fact.MonthlyFactOrgMap AS a
   INNER JOIN Dim.DimOrganisation AS b ON a.DimOrganisationKey = b.DimOrganisationKey
   INNER JOIN Dim.DimDate AS c ON a.DateKey = c.DateKey
   WHERE (c.CalendarYear = 2014)
     AND (c.FullDate BETWEEN b.RowStartDate AND b.RowEndDate)
     AND (c.MonthName IN ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June'))
     AND (a.ExpenseClaimCount > 0)) AS q
   GROUP BY MonthName
   ORDER BY MIN(c.FullDate);
```

Comment: This worked Gordon but can we find any more simpler query, just curious..Its the sql server database

Comment: In SQL Server, you can use the `choose()` function for the first approach, but you'll probably like the second method better.

Comment: as this query is part of a union , so Union doesn't support order by that way.

Comment: You will have to be careful hard coding this, if a month outside of these appears in the results it won't sort correctly.

Comment: @Patrick . . . That is correct and I would strongly advise using the edited approach.  It also works for date spans that include multiple years.

Comment: @user3803420 . . . Changing the question after people have already answered it is considered impolite.  That can invalidate answers and cause downvotes on what were once completely reasonable answers.  If you have another question, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to convert the string to a number, which can be done by converting it to a DATE format and then getting the MM datepart from it.

```
-- the day and year don't matter because we only care about month
DATEPART(MM, CONVERT(DATE, [MonthName] + '01, 2000', 110))
```

So your query would look something like this

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(MM, CONVERT(DATE, 'May' + '01, 2000', 110))
    MonthName,
       SUM(ExpenseClaimCount) AS Expr1,
       'EXPENSE-CLAIM' AS ROW_TYPE
FROM
  (SELECT b.OrganisationID,
          a.ExpenseClaimCount,
          c.MonthName
   FROM Fact.MonthlyFactOrgMap AS a
   INNER JOIN Dim.DimOrganisation AS b ON a.DimOrganisationKey = b.DimOrganisationKey
   INNER JOIN Dim.DimDate AS c ON a.DateKey = c.DateKey
   WHERE (c.CalendarYear = 2014)
     AND (c.FullDate BETWEEN b.RowStartDate AND b.RowEndDate)
     AND (c.MonthName IN ('March',
                          'April',
                          'May',
                          'June'))
     AND (a.ExpenseClaimCount > 0)) AS q
GROUP BY DATEPART(MM, CONVERT(DATE, 'May' + '01, 2000', 110)), MonthName
ORDER BY DATEPART(MM, CONVERT(DATE, 'May' + '01, 2000', 110))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `monthname` matches the month in `fulldate`:

```
SELECT MonthName,
       SUM(ExpenseClaimCount) AS Expr1,
       'EXPENSE-CLAIM' AS ROW_TYPE
FROM
(
    SELECT b.OrganisationID,
    a.ExpenseClaimCount,
    c.MonthName,
    c.FullDate
    FROM Fact.MonthlyFactOrgMap AS a
    INNER JOIN Dim.DimOrganisation AS b ON a.DimOrganisationKey = b.DimOrganisationKey
    INNER JOIN Dim.DimDate AS c ON a.DateKey = c.DateKey
    WHERE (c.CalendarYear = 2014)
    AND (c.FullDate BETWEEN b.RowStartDate AND b.RowEndDate)
    AND (c.MonthName IN ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June'))
    AND (a.ExpenseClaimCount > 0)
) AS q
GROUP BY MonthName
order by (DATEPART(month,FullDate) + 8) % 12
```

Otherwise you'll need to join a table giving the date order to your table to get a numeric version of the month name; example here using a common table expression to generate a virtual table for this purpose:

```
;with cteMonths (name, monthDate) as
(
    select datename(month,'1900-01-01'), cast('1900-01-01' as date)

    union all

    select DATENAME(month,dateadd(month,1,monthdate))
    ,dateadd(month,1,monthdate)
    from ctemonths 
    where monthDate < '1900-12-01'
)
SELECT MonthName,
       SUM(ExpenseClaimCount) AS Expr1,
       'EXPENSE-CLAIM' AS ROW_TYPE
FROM
(
    SELECT b.OrganisationID,
    a.ExpenseClaimCount,
    c.MonthName
    FROM Fact.MonthlyFactOrgMap AS a
    INNER JOIN Dim.DimOrganisation AS b ON a.DimOrganisationKey = b.DimOrganisationKey
    INNER JOIN Dim.DimDate AS c ON a.DateKey = c.DateKey
    WHERE (c.CalendarYear = 2014)
    AND (c.FullDate BETWEEN b.RowStartDate AND b.RowEndDate)
    AND (c.MonthName IN ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June'))
    AND (a.ExpenseClaimCount > 0)
) AS q
inner join
(
    select name
    , (DATEPART(month,monthdate) + 8) % 12 displayOrder
    from cteMonths 
) x
on x.name = q.monthname
GROUP BY MonthName
order by x.displayOrder
```

**Explanation**

- `(DATEPART(month,fulldate) + 8) % 12` is the important bit of this code.
- `datepart` extracts the numeric value of the month (e.g. `2014-07-03` -> 7)
- `% 12` means is the mathematic modulus function; i.e. what's the remainder after I divide this number by 12; so `7 % 12` is 7, `12 % 12` is 0, and `14 % 12` is 2.
- `+8` provides an offset to make April the first month; since 4 (april) + 8 = 12, and 12 % 12 = 0, making this the first in the sequence.
- I did `+8` instead of `-4` as a workaround for a SQL nuance; in SQL `-1 % 12` is -1; in most other systems it would be 11.  By adding 8 we avoid the need to deal with negative numbers, so avoid this issue.